# File uploading with Connect

Tags: javascript, node.js, node.js-connect

Im trying to upload a file and examine it with a this simple code.

```
var connect = require("connect")
    , http = require('http');

var app = connect()
    .use(connect.logger('dev'))
    .use(connect.static('static'))
    .use(connect.bodyParser())
    .use(function(req, res, next){
        if ('POST' == req.method) {
            console.log(req.body);
            console.log(req.body.file);
            res.writeHead(200);
            res.end('Uploaded');
        } else {
            next();
        }
    });

connect.createServer(app).listen(3000);
```

In the static folder i have this index.html:

```
 <form action="/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="text" name="texten">
     <input type="file" name="displayImage">

     <button>Send file!</button>
 </form>
```

In the browser I write some text in the text-field, choose a simple .txt file for the file-input. Then i press submit.

In the console the content of the textfield is outputted as expected, but the file or information about it is nowhere to be found.

**Q:** Where in req.body are the file located, and how to i access the information about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

multipart submissions required for your file upload are not handled by `bodyparser`. You will need some other middleware such as [`connect-busboy`](https://github.com/mscdex/connect-busboy) or [`connect-multiparty`](https://github.com/andrewrk/connect-multiparty).

You could then access the uploaded file from the `req.files` object.

Answer (score 0):

You should use file system core module to write the content of the body to file.